# Several mail servers(domains) on one physical server

Tags: linux, networking, email, dns

A weird use-case rises apon me. Soon I will be given the task to configure a dedicated server (with one public IPv4 address) in rather a weird way. For starters, there will be many domains.

My vision is to create a container/VM machine (haven't decided yet), each will be assigned to a domain.

Each container/VM with a domain is going to have it's mail server. And now comes the big question. Is it possible, to set up multiple mail servers on a single IPv4 address?

Linux/GNU - based OS is going to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use postfix and dovecot set up through Virtualmin (free, virtualmin.com) in a shared environment.  This allows adding many domains with pop/imap/SMTP support on only one ip address. Also check out roundcube for a webmail client.  No need for multiple virtual servers.

Comment: And what is your revDNS  record? Have you done anything with your server's hostname?

Comment: Just make sure the rdns points back to the server's main hostname, and be sure to define SPF records for all domains being hosted.  Also be sure to check the blacklists regularly to ensure your public ip is not listed.  Additionally, be sure not to run an open SMTP relay, by requiring all senders to authenticate.  Open relays will get you blacklisted quickly.